# System.Reflections - CSharp Interpreteur

Tags: c#, dll, .net-assembly, system.reflection

I am trying to make a little app which reads codes (given files) and must parse them. It may not compile, because the code I am providing is already compiled. **What I need** is that I can read all infos of the code using something similar to `System.Reflections (FieldInfo, MethodInfo, ...)`.

I have tried compiling that code as a DLL and then use:

```
((Assembly)assembly).GetExportedTypes()[x].GetMethods ();
((Assembly)assembly).GetExportedTypes()[x].GetFields ();
```

It does a lot of the work, but I am facing the problem that it gives me **Only the public declarations**: (only the public methods, and public fields)
I am unable to read less access declarations, (private, internal, protected).

How can I obtain this?

Additional Info: I just need the names and the types of the declarations

```
{methodType, methodName, variableType, variableName}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`BindingFlags`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
((Assembly)assembly).GetExportedTypes()[x].GetMethods(flags);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked perfectly, that was what i was missing, thanks.

Comment: i have tried using this, even tried using 'var flags = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase;' but only some variables are being loaded, what can be the problem?

Comment: @MarkSmethwick what do you mean by some? which members you are not getting?

Comment: sorry, all fixed, it was an error because before compiling the dll, my code were replacing some text by mistake, so it was throwing me errors, which i didn't looked up, so not all declaration were visible

Answer (score 0):

You should pass BindingFlags to your GetMethods/GetFields etc. calls.
Read this: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags(v=vs.110).aspx).